# Sync Windows Server shares with OneDrive

Tags: backup, synchronization, shared-storage

Recently one of my costumers bought office 365 and now we have a slew of space online we would like to fill, so we would like to sync some main folders from WS2012 to it so it's always accessible and up to day.

What's the best way? I've tried onedrive but with no luck, is there any open source software you guys recommend? Preferably like a service that syncs any changes made

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what Office 365 subscription/license this customer has, but if it includes Sharepoint Online, Microsoft has a free mihration tool that can migrate shared folders to Sharepoint Online Document Libraries. It needs to be manually run, but you can probably figure out how to automate it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool